# Animate FromQuarternionTo3DRotation nb file with 4 quarternion values

Tags: manipulate, import, animation, geometry, quaternions

I have a csv file. Inside the csv file, there are few rows of 4 quartenion values. I would like to animate the quarternion nb in http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FromQuaternionTo3DRotation/

I believe I should begin with this line

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\a.csv", "List"]
```

But what should I do to animate the quarternion? Below is the quarternion code.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{mod, theta, axemin, axemax, rayon, u, v, w},
  mod = Sqrt[a^2 + ax^2 + ay^2 + az^2];
  theta = ArcCos[a/mod];
  axemin = -2.5;
  axemax = 2.5;
  rayon = 2;
  u = {ax/Sin[theta]/mod, ay/Sin[theta]/mod, az/Sin[theta]/mod}; 
  v = Cross[u, {Cos[3 Pi/4], Sin[3 Pi/4], 0}]/
    Norm[Cross[u, {Cos[3 Pi/4], Sin[3 Pi/4], 0}]];
  w = Cross[u, {Cos[3 Pi/4 + theta], Sin[3 Pi/4 + theta], 0}]/
    Norm[Cross[u, {Cos[3 Pi/4 + theta], Sin[3 Pi/4 + theta], 0}]];
  Show[
   Graphics3D[{ Thickness[0.003],
     Line[{{axemin, 0, 0}, {axemax, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{0, axemin, 0}, {0, axemax, 0}}],
     Line[{{0, 0, axemin}, {0, 0, axemax}}],
     Arrowheads[0.03],
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {axemax, 0, 0}}],
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, axemax, 0}}],
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, axemax}}],
     Text[Style["x", Italic, 12], {0.92 axemax, 0, 0.2}],
     Text[Style["y", Italic, 12], {0, 0.92 axemax, 0.2}],
     Text[Style["z", Italic, 12], {0.2, 0, 0.92 axemax}],
     Opacity[0.5], Cylinder[{+0 u, 0.01 u}, rayon], Blue, 
     Thickness[0.007],
     Opacity[0.9], Line[{1.5*axemin*u, 1.5*axemax*u}], 
     Thickness[0.003],
     Red, Line[{0.01*u, 0.01*u + rayon*v}],
     Line[{0.01*u, 0.01*u + rayon*w}],
     Thickness[0.005],
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.01*u + 0.7*rayon*v}],
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.01*u + 0.7*rayon*w}],
     Text[
      Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)", 
       12], {0.01*u + 0.7*rayon*v + 0.2*u}], 
     Text[Style[Row[{Style["r", Italic], "(", (
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(Style["\<v\>", Plain, 
            Bold]\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)), ")"}], 
       12], {0.01*u + 0.7*rayon*w + 0.3*u}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{axemin, axemax}, {axemin, axemax}, {axemin, 
       axemax}}, ImageSize -> 1.2 {350, 350}], 
   ParametricPlot3D[
    0.01*u + 
     0.7*rayon*
      Cross[u, {Cos[3 Pi/4 + t], Sin[3 Pi/4 + t], 0}]/
       Norm[Cross[u, {Cos[3 Pi/4 + t], Sin[3 Pi/4 + t], 0}]], {t, 0, 
     theta}, PlotStyle -> Red]]],
 Delimiter,
 Text@Style[
   Row[{"quaternion: ", "\[ScriptCapitalA]", " = ", Style["a", Italic],
      " + ", Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(x\)]\)", Italic], 
     " ", Style["i", Bold],
     " + ", Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(y\)]\)", Italic], " ", 
     Style["j", Bold],
     " + ", Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(z\)]\)", Italic], " ", 
     Style["k", Bold]}], 12], {{a, 0, 
   Text@Style["a", Italic, 12]}, -2, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled",
   ImageSize -> Small}, {{ax, 0.5, 
   Text@Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(x\)]\)", Italic, 12]}, -2, 
  2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Small}, {{ay, 0.5, 
   Text@Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(y\)]\)", Italic, 12]}, -2, 
  2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Small}, {{az, 0.5, 
   Text@Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(z\)]\)", Italic, 12]}, -2, 
  2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Comment: Don't forget to format your code.

Comment: If only we had that *.csv file...

Comment: This is the content. Sorry for not uploading as I dunno how to do so.

0,-0.019878445,0.2981767,0.9543037
0.036677353,0.02482699,0.6954033,0.71725357
0,0,-0.99989706,-0.014346213